# How to get activity instance from startActivity() or precisely how to call a method in an activity that we create?

Tags: android, android-activity, parameter-passing, android-adapter

Im trying to figure a way how to call an activity that an adapter has started. Is there a way to get the instance of the activity from startactivity and make a method call into the activity ?

I'ved got an adapter that has a list

```
     public class LanguageDownloadRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LanguageDownloadRVAdapter.DownloadViewHolder>{
```

And in this adapter, it starts a particular activity called MainActivity

```
                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MainActivity.class));
                ((Activity)context).finish();
```

Here is the MainActivity that it starts

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements IabBroadcastListener{
```

How can I make a call from the adapter to a method in the MainActivity. (im just trying to perform inapp purchase which is implemented in the MainActivity). so how can i do something like this.

```
mainactivity.perform_inapp_purchase();
```

Comment: make static method which can be called by using activity name not the object

Comment: As soon as you start the new Activity, you no longer have the adapter being visible, so you may want to restructure your app methods or show a [mcve]  so you can get a proper solution

Comment: @anjali static wont work, i tried it. the static method cant call an internal method.

Comment: @cricket_007 you might be right about that. i thought the activity is reused. someone wrote me this code.

Comment: You are welcome to cast a Context to the Activity and call the method, but I'm guessing there's a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use EventBus for passing data between activity and list adapter. You can do it in the same way for passing data between activity and fragment.
This work the same way as storing data in global variable (in a fancier way)

Comment: Try to give more detail in that answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can store the instance in the application class, but you should be careful about the memory leaks. 
In the onCreate of your activity

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
// get the instance using this and store it in the application class or in the place that you want to call from it
}
```

From where will you call your method?
I didn't understand the situation.

Answer (score 0):

In the adapter:

Add a new Field `private Context mContext;`

In the adapter Constructor add one more parameter as below, and assign it into class level variable:

```
public LanguageDownloadRVAdapter(......,Context context){
    //your code.
    this.mContext=context;
}
```

In the Adapter where you want to call Activity's `perform_inapp_purchase()` method:

```
if(mContext instanceof MainActivity){
   ((MainActivity) mContext).perform_inapp_purchase();
}
```

> More Generalized Approach:

If you need to use this same adapter for more than one activity then :

> Create an Interface

```
public interface InAppPerchaceInterface{
    void perform_inapp_purchase();
}
```

> Implement this interface in activities

Then in `Adapter`, call like below:

```
if(mContext instanceof InAppPerchaceInterface){
       ((InAppPerchaceInterface) mContext).perform_inapp_purchase();
}
```

Comment: @Axil did it help?